# Resizing an image to keep everything on screen

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to make one central image scale properly to the rest of the screen that way it does not push the rest of the objects off the android screen.

[Here is my code](http://pastebin.com/TfUhtUJ7) (formatting something like this is a big pain in StackOverflow)

[And here is my XML for the selected class.](http://pastebin.com/wBtGb4V1)

> I am trying to resize the *hangmanPhoto* that way the scrollview at
>   the bottom of the screen is not pushed off the screen if the user
>   inputs a very long word.
>
> ie: user inputs "This is a very long word" into the
>   *hiddenPhraseLabel2* or the *clueLabel*.
>
> If you need more clarification, this is an android application i am
>   making for school and it is supposed to be a user-determined "Custom
>   Game" for the game of Hangman.

The user can set the word and a clue to pass off to their friend and if they input such a long word or clue, the horizontal scroll view (Which contains the letters A-Z) at the bottom of the application get's cut off by the boundaries of the screen.

I feel like this is a very complex problem, so if you can help me it would be greatly appreciated!

*ALL LINKS ARE PASTEBIN LINKS: HERE THEY ARE AS FOLLOWS*

- http://pastebin.com/TfUhtUJ7 Java Code
- http://pastebin.com/wBtGb4V1 XML Code